# data.frame has more columns than expected

Tags: r, dataframe

I am downloading data through the NY Times API, and I run into a strange error about while trying to row bind multiple dataframes.

I obtain two rows and two columns from the data.frame as follows:

```
a = head(nydata[,c(5,9)],2)
```

This is the dput() result:

```
> dput(a)
structure(list(print_page = c(NA, "4"), headline = structure(list(
    main = c("Donald Trump’s Letter", "A Rabbi’s Enduring Sermon on Living Your Last Five Minutes"
    ), content_kicker = c(NA, "On Religion"), kicker = c(NA, 
    "On Religion"), print_headline = c(NA, "The Enduring Lessons of ‘Five Minutes to Live’"
    )), .Names = c("main", "content_kicker", "kicker", "print_headline"
), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("print_page", 
"headline"), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
```

attributes(a) shows that the dataframe indeed has two columns.

```
> attributes(a)
$names
[1] "print_page" "headline"  

$row.names
[1] 1 2

$class
[1] "data.frame"
```

But a summary shows otherwise!

```
> summary(a)
  print_page          headline.main     headline.content_kicker   headline.kicker    headline.print_headline
 Length:2           Length:2            Length:2            Length:2            Length:2                    
 Class :character   Class :character    Class :character    Class :character    Class :character            
 Mode  :character   Mode  :character    Mode  :character    Mode  :character    Mode  :character
```

I think that when I resolve this, I'll be able to rowbind the dataframes. Does this look familiar to anyone, or does anyone know what causes this inconsistency?

Thanks!

Comment: You have a second column as a data.frame if you check `str(a)`.  One option is to `do.call(data.frame, a)`, make a regular data.frame with 5 columns instead of 1 data.frame with a nested second data.frame as column

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! There is another column which also consists of data.frames but with multiple rows, do.call(data.frame,a) returns an error there (implies different number of rows). But I know what the cause of my problem is, so I think I can solve the issue now. Thanks!